# installing and using ffmpeg on mamp under mac snow leopard

Tags: php, ffmpeg

hi i was wondering if anyone knew how to install ffmpeg on mac
then how would i link it to mamp so that i can use it with php?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

`ffmpeg` can be installed using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). If you just need the binary available for PHP scripts to execute, then you're good to go once it's installed. Just use `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` as the path to the `ffmpeg` binary.

I can't be more specific about the "link to MAMP" part unless you tell us what PHP package depends on ffmpeg.

---

After "sudo brew install ffmpeg" I have this in my terminal:

```
adam@fsck:~:0$ sudo brew install ffmpeg
[--snip--]
==> Downloading http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.6.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --disable-indev=jack --enable-libx264 --enable-
==> make install
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.6: 91 files, 15M, built in 2.3 minutes
adam@fsck:~:0$ which ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

So, my `ffmpeg` is indeed in `/usr/local/bin` via Homebrew.

Comment: ffmpeg doesnt exist in the bin folder. would it be somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) then:

```
sudo port selfupdate 

sudo port install ffmpeg
```

Comment: and where would the ffmpeg be installed using your way?

Answer (score 0):

i've done exactly this [guide to install ffmpeg](http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html)

It worked like a charm.